# How to print Exception Name in Oracle Stored Procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am using `FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE` function which is only printing line number with package name. I want to print exception name along this.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a common practice to use `format_error_stack` along with `format_error_backtrace`. Something like this.

```
DECLARE
     x INT;
BEGIN
 x :='A';
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
     dbms_output.put_line(SUBSTR( DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack 
                 || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace, 1, 4000));
END;
/
```

Result

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You may also use `SQLERRM` which gives you the error message, but it is [not recommended](http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/09/plsql-101-three-ways-to-get-error.html)

Even better, for Oracle 12c and above there's [**UTL_CALL_STACK**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_call_stack.htm#ARPLS74078) which can give you far detailed information of the error and also has much greater flexibility for debugging and error handling of PL/SQL code.

Comment: And here's a LiveSQL link to several scripts on utl_call_stack to help you use this package. https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:49:::NO:RP,49:P49_SEARCH:utl_call_stack